# How do I run or echo HTML snippets in Quarto?

Tags: html, r, quarto

I'm quite new to Quarto and still try to figure basic things out.

Is there a way to run or echo HTML code chunks in Quarto?

This does not work:

```
{html}
#| echo: false
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Test
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Title</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

So what is the correct way to do it (if it's possible at all)?

EDIT: This works, but only for echo.

````
``` html
<a href="#">Test</a>
```
````

Can I run the code instead and embed the result into the PDF file as a static image? Is there an automatic way to do this?

Kind regards
winnewoerp

Comment: You could have a look at the `webshot` package.

Comment: Thank you! Sounds like a very good solution. I will try that.

Comment: @winnewoerp, one possible approach you can try is that writing a knit hooks that capture the html content, render it and then pass it to webshot and lastly returns the webshot image.